# Database copy limit per database reached. The database X cannot have more than 10 concurrent database copies (Azure SQL)

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

In our application, we have a master database 'X'. For each new client, we will create a new database copy of master database 'X'.

I am using the following SQL command which will be executed against Azure SQL server.

```
CREATE DATABASE [NEW NAME] AS COPY OF [MASTER DB]
```

We are using a custom queue tier so that we can create more than one client at a time parallelly.

I am facing issues in following scenario.

I am trying to create 70 clients. Once 25 clients got created I am getting below error.

```
Database copy limit per database reached. The database 'BlankDBClient' cannot have more than 10 concurrent database copies
```

Can you please share your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure has logic to do various operations online/automatically for you (backups, upgrades, etc).  There are IOs required to do each copy, so there are limits in place because the machine does not have infinite iops. (Those limits may change a bit over time as we work to improve the service, get newer hardware, etc).

In terms of what options you have, you could:

- Restore N databases from a database backup (which would still have IO limits but they may be higher for you depending on your reservation size)
- Consider models to copy in parallel using a single source to hierarchically create what you need (copy 2 from one, then copy 2 from each of the ones you just copied, etc)
- Stage out the copies over time based on the limits you get back from the system.
- Try a larger reservation size for the source and target during the copy to get more IOPS and lower the time to perform the operations.

Comment: Agree with your suggestion. only concern is cost. Since increasing IOPS involves cost, solution shared by Albert should be reliable in long term. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Connor answer, you can consider to a have a dacpac or bacpac of that master database stored on Azure Storage and once you have submitted 25 concurrent database copies you can start restoring the dacpac from Azure Storage.

You can also monitor how many database copies are showing COPYING on the state_desc column of the following queries, after sending the first batch of 25 copies, and when those queries return less than 25 rows, start sending more copies until reaching  the 25 limit. Keep doing this until finishing the queue of copies required.

```
   Select
     [sys].[databases].[name], 
       [sys].[databases].[state_desc], 
       [sys].[dm_database_copies].[start_date], 
       [sys].[dm_database_copies].[modify_date], 
       [sys].[dm_database_copies].[percent_complete],
             [sys].[dm_database_copies].[error_code], 
       [sys].[dm_database_copies].[error_desc], 
       [sys].[dm_database_copies].[error_severity], 
       [sys].[dm_database_copies].[error_state]
   From
      [sys].[databases]
   Left
 Outer
 Join
 [sys].[dm_database_copies] 
   On
    [sys].[databases].[database_id] = [sys].[dm_database_copies].[database_id]
   Where
   [sys].[databases].[state_desc] = 'COPYING'


SELECT state_desc, * 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE [state_desc] = 'COPYING'
```

Comment: Thanks for your time on this. In our case dacpac might not be good option since we can have any number of master databases. I mean we don't have a control on how many master databases we can have across the application.

Comment: By checking the number of databases which are in COPYING status, then issuing further database creation command make sense. Thanks for your suggestions and time on this.

Comment: You are welcome! Hope it helps you build your final solution.